# PHP / Apache on localhost is displaying wrong float value

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I'm not sure why this is happening, but on my localhost, I'm not sure if it's PHP or Apache, but when I have a number like `123.45` and I do `floatval("123.45")` I end up getting `123.4500000000234813423...` I can do an `sprintf` to show the correct value, but the end result needs to be `float` or `int`, basically a number.

Comment: Google "php float precision"

Comment: can you use in your app round instead of float? round(123.45, 2); ?

Comment: Look at [this link](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: No, any helper that rounds it for me in php returns a string, not a number.

Comment: Thanks @MikeW, I'll take a read at this.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [Floating Point Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Use `number_format` or `sprintf` to **display** proper value.

PHP Docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned above, I've used these techniques, but they return a string, and I need it to be a number.

Comment: @Samer: it just **displays** string